# Creating a view that filters based on a flag

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to write a query to summarize a table.

I'm wondering that the most efficient way to do so is.

My data is organized as such:

```
ID | Value | Flag.
----------------------
1 | 45 | 0
1 | 52 | 1
2 | 35 | 0
3 | 50 | 0
```

If an ID repeats twice, than I want to take the value where the flag=1, otherwise I want to take zero

My Attempt:

```
Select ID, 
case when (select count(*) from table a2 where a2.id = a.id) = 2 THEN
     1
ELSE
     0
END flag,
case when (select count(*) from table a2 where a2.id = a.id) = 2 THEN
     (select a2.value from table a2 where a2.id = a.id)
ELSE
     a.value
END value
from table a
```

^^This will result in

```
1 | 52 | 1
1 | 52 | 1
2 | 35 | 0
3 | 50 | 0
```

I still need to get rid of the duplicates (ie. the first or second entry needs to be removed since now I only want 1 value per ID), but before I go any further, I've realized that this probably isn't the most ideal when it comes to efficiency.

Comment: Rows in a table are ***NOT*** "sorted" - there is no such thing as "the first row" in a table or a query unless you specify an order using `order by`. So you need some kind of condition that makes you pick 52 over 45 in your example.

Comment: Can you really do `case when (select count(*) from table a2 where a2.id = a.id) = 2 THEN
     (select a2.value from table where a2.id = a.id)` this? a2 in not in the `then` part

Comment: @GurwinderSingh my mistake, that was a typo, and yes, I tried it in plsql before posting it here

Comment: @TheMuffinBoy is `flag` column present in the input table?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh, Yes. I want to take value that has the flag enabled. The max value won't work because sometimes the flag value will be lower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using window functions.

However rows in a table are not sorted in any way. There is no such thing as "the first row" (or the second or the last) **unless** you use an `order by`

If you e.g. want to pick the highest `value` for each id (or you don't actually care which value you pick) you can use:

```
select id, 
       value
from (
  select id, 
         value
         row_number() over (partition by id order by value desc) as rn
  from the_table
) 
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: If flag = 1 than I take that value, otherwise I take whatever is in the database. I've never heard of partition or windows before, so you've given me someone to look into. Thanks.

Comment: If the flag exists, either in the base table or as the result of prior processing, then the ORDER BY inside the ROW_NUMBER() call should be ORDER BY FLAG.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name See :P

Comment: @mathguy: the `flag` column does not exist in the database. It's an expression based on the count of values for the ID column. As the intent is to pick one ID if there are duplicates there is no need to generate that flag in the first place.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - my bad, I didn't read the OP's code (I usually don't, when the OP says the code doesn't do what is needed). You are absolutely right, the code generates the flag. In that case, if it's only about an id and one of the many values, I don't see why a simple aggregation (take `MAX(value)` or whatever) isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

First, copied from @a_horse_with_no_name.

Second, partition ordering needs to be based on `flag` not `value` as expressed in the question. However, In case there are multiple rows with same id and flag, you need to decide which should be picked up, maybe go with the `max` value by doing `order by flag desc, value desc` instead in the partitioning - depends on your need.

```
select id, 
       value,
       flag
from (
  select id, 
         value,
         flag,
         row_number() over (partition by id order by flag desc) rn
  from my_table
) 
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: The `flag` columns is *evaluated* based on the duplicates, there is no such column in the table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It is. see the question. *If an ID repeats twice, than I want to take the value where the flag=1* and sample data

Comment: It is not: `case when .. END flag` - it's calculated using the CASE expression